# Do all infinite posets contain an isomorphic proper subposet.

Tags: order-theory

Given an infinite poset $P$, does it always contain a proper subposet $Q \subsetneq P$ such that $P$ and $Q$ are isomorphic as posets?

What motivated this question is the following. It can be seen that for the natural number poset given by the divisibility relation, there are (uncountably) infinitely many ways of choosing a subset that is isomorphic to the original poset. Indeed, letting $\mathbb{P}$ be the set of primes, consider any sequence of sets $(A_i)_{i \in \mathbb{P}}$, where $A_i \subseteq \mathbb{N}_{> 0}$, and all of $A_i$ are infinite. Then the subposet of $(\mathbb{N}, |)$ given by those positive integers whose prime decomposition is $p_1^{k_1} \cdots p_r^{k_r}$ where $k_i \in A_{p_i}$ is isomorphic to the original poset, and furthermore if we select at least one $A_i \neq \mathbb{N}_{>0}$ we have that it is a proper subposet.

This seems like an interesting property, so I wondered which other posets might share it. I could find no counter-example to this being true in general for all infinite posets.

On the other hand, I have no idea on how to prove such a fact. The class of infinite posets is very rich and I wasn't able to find any structure to hang on to in order to prove this.

Comment: OK, thank you for the feedback, I have added the motivation for the problem -- it wasn't a homework question, rather just something I was curious about which I don't see a way to prove.

Comment: What if A contains B, C, and D, D contains E and F, F contains G and H, H contains I and J, J contains K and L, and so on?

Comment: @GerryMyerson If you remove B and C from your poset, don't you get a poset isomorphic to the one you started with?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry, I mean, remove B and D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n\ge2$ let $P_n$ be a poset with $2n$ elements whose [comparability graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparability_graph) is a cycle. Then the disjoint union
$$P=P_2\sqcup P_3\sqcup P_4\sqcup\cdots$$
is not isomorphic to any of its proper subsets.

The graph $P_n$ can be described as having elements $a_1,\dots,a_n$ and $b_1,\dots,b_n$ with $a_i\lt b_i$ for all $i$, and $a_i\lt b_{i-1}$ for $1\lt i\le n$, and $a_1\lt b_n$; in other words,
$$a_1\lt b_1\gt a_2\lt b_2\gt a_3\lt b_3\gt\cdots\gt a_n\lt b_n\gt a_1.$$

Comment: On the other hand, every countably infinite **totally** ordered set **is** isomorphic to a proper subset of itself. However, you can use transfinite recursion to construct an uncountable set $X\subset\mathbb R$ such that the only strictly increasing function $f:X\to X$ is the identity.

Comment: Thank you! I wonder if there is a counterexample of every cardinality?

Comment: You mean every infinite cardinality. I have no idea. You could ask that as a new question.

Comment: For another followup question, we could require that the comparability graph is connected.

Comment: @Karl Can't we just add a top element to my example?